# Why is 1 << 3 equal to 8 and not 6?

Tags: c, bit-shift

In `C` I have this `enum`:

```
enum {
    STAR_NONE =     1 << 0, // 1
    STAR_ONE =      1 << 1, // 2
    STAR_TWO =      1 << 2, // 4
    STAR_THREE =    1 << 3  // 8
};
```

Why is `1 << 3` equal to 8 and not 6?

Comment: Why is `1 << 2` equal to 4 and not 3?

Comment: You input `3 << 1` into that bitshift calculator website, not `1 << 3`.

Comment: Left shifting a number by x bits is nothing but multiplying the number by (2^x) and right shifting by x bits is dividing by (2^x)! Additional info: That's why many times bit shifting is used instead of Multiplication and Division for faster operation!

Comment: @Swanand That formula made everything a thousand times more clear, thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe this sounds stupid but I thought because 3 << 1 = 6, the other way around too

Comment: @YassineHoussni: You're right; it does ;) It's best to _research_ and _understand_ what things do, rather than wildly guessing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit lol! Yeah, I am completely new to bitshifting, I just started researchen, I've never used it before but now I took the step to learn about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shifting a number to the left is equivalent to multiplying that number by 2<sup>n</sup> where `n` is the distance you shifted that number.

To see how is that true lets take an example, suppose we have the number `5` so we shift it `2` places to the left, `5` in binary is `00000101` i.e.

> 0×2<sup>7</sup> + 0×2<sup>6</sup> + 0×2<sup>5</sup> + 0×2<sup>4</sup> + 0×2<sup>3</sup> + 1×2<sup>2</sup> + 0×2<sup>1</sup> + 1×2<sup>0</sup> = 1×2<sup>2</sup> + 1×2<sup>0</sup> = 4 + 1 = 5

now, `5 << 2` would be `00010100` i.e.

> 0×2<sup>7</sup> + 0×2<sup>6</sup> + 0×2<sup>5</sup> + 1×2<sup>4</sup> + 0×2<sup>3</sup> + 1×2<sup>2</sup> + 0×2<sup>1</sup> + 0×2<sup>0</sup> = 1×2<sup>4</sup> + 1×2<sup>2</sup> = 16 + 4 = 20

But we can write *1×2<sup>4</sup> + 1×2<sup>2</sup>* as

> 1×2<sup>4</sup> + 1×2<sup>2</sup> = (1×2<sup>2</sup> + 1×2<sup>0</sup>)×2<sup>2</sup> = 5×4 → 20

and from this, it is possible to conclude that `5 << 2` is equivalent to 5×2<sup>2</sup>, it would be possible to demonstrate that in general

> k << m = k×2<sup>m</sup>

So in your case `1 << 3` is equivalent to 2<sup>3</sup> = 8, since

`1 << 3` → `b00000001 << 3` → `b00001000` → 2<sup>3</sup> -> 8

If you instead did this `3 << 1` then

`3 << 1` → `b00000011 << 1` → `b00000110` → 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> → 4 + 2 → 6

Comment: Sometimes [terseness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28396041/2410359) beats completeness - like your fine complete answer.

Comment: @chux not this time. Thanks iharob for the answer, this is exactly what I needed to get a clear view about shifting.

Answer (score 3):

1 in binary is `0000 0001`

by shifting to left by 3 bits (i.e. `1 << 3`) you get

```
0000 1000
```

Which is 8 in decimal and not 6.

Comment: Thank you, I just started to learn about bitshifting!

Answer (score 1):

Because two to the power of three is eight.

Answer (score 1):

Think in binary.
You are actually doing this.
0001 shifted 3 times to the left = 1000 = 8